# Counting problem based on Hackerrank competition

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Given a very large number(`N`)(say it has 500 digits) we have to count number of pairs of integers `x` and `y` such that 0 <= x < y <= N, and sum(x) < sum(y), where sum(k) = sum of digits of number `k`.

Source : [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/morgan-stanley-codeathon-2017/challenges/dreamplay-and-clubbing)

As always I dont't expect a good tutorial from Hackerrank so I asked here, any pointers will be of great help.

PS : Contest is over now.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the value of N (so the problem has a single answer), or are you asking to develop an algorithm for a general value?

Comment: The solution of this problem is based on Dynamic Programming. if this is the first time with DP, I advise you to study a simple problem before tackling more complicated ones.

Comment: @awkward yes, we know the number `N`, and @mounirbensalem yes i am familiar with DP but this was like count number of pairs, so this was hard for me.

Comment: @awkward actually i am looking for algorithm for general `N` value, yes.